# Why is auto connecting to Wi-Fi with WifiManager resulting in no access to the local IP address it's connected to?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, networking, mobile

I'm trying to auto-connect to a local network with no internet access. I am able to connect to it successfully, but I can't access the network's IP address. If I connect to the network manually via Wi-Fi settings on my tablet, I am able to hit that same IP address inside Chrome. What would cause this behavior?

Here is my code to connect to the Wi-Fi:

````
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
   suspend fun connectToWifi(ssid: String, pin: String): WifiState = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
       val connectivityManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
       val specifier = WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
           .setSsid(ssid)
           .setWpa2Passphrase(pin)
           .setSsidPattern(PatternMatcher(ssid, PatternMatcher.PATTERN_PREFIX))
           .build()
       val request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
           .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
           .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
           .build()
       val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
           var resumed = false

           override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
               super.onAvailable(network)
               if (!resumed) {
                   wifiState.value = WifiState.Connected
                //   connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network)
                   continuation.resume(WifiState.Connected)
                   resumed = true
               }
           }

           override fun onUnavailable() {
               super.onUnavailable()
               if (!resumed) {
                   wifiState.value = WifiState.Disconnected
                   continuation.resume(WifiState.Disconnected)
                   resumed = true
               }
           }

           override fun onLost(network: Network) {
               super.onLost(network)
               if (!resumed) {
                   wifiState.value = WifiState.Disconnected
                   continuation.resume(WifiState.Disconnected)
                   resumed = true
               }
           }
       }



       connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback)
   } ```

I've tried adding **.addCapability(Int.MAX_VALUE)** but that did not resolve anything.
````